# Ambari UI are not in sync with Ranger

Tags: apache

Getting User:amb_ranger_admin credentials on Ambari UI are not in sync with Ranger. can you please let me know what config changes are required for this.

Thanks

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can refer below link

http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.4/bk_Ranger_Install_Guide/content/updating_ranger_admin_passwords.html

Passdowrd for Configs > Advanced ranger-env in the fields labeled admin_username and Ranger Admin user's password for Ambari should match.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not true. The user in Advanced ranger-env (default admin) is the administrator user for the Ranger UI, and the user in the field "Ranger Admin username for Ambari" (default amb_ranger_admin) is for internal use of Ambari when creating/editing policy profiles. They are for different uses and don't need to have same password and indeed using the same is a security issue.
The problem is these 2 users must have the same password in Ambari as defined inside the Ranger Admin UI (http:6082 or https:6182).